# Business Leads Icon

Tags: icon, interface-design, business

I'm building an interface for an admin page. The admin clicks a button to choose an icon to see how many business leads received.

I have always been stumped as to which icon is best suited for use on the "Business Leads" button.

My best idea was to use a magnet, but was wondering is there's a standard icon for "Business Leads"?

Comment: To my mind a lead is a human being, so I have always gone with the classic "user" icon / avatar

Comment: It's a Business Leads, I have already tried a user icon/avatar. But, expecting something more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

I would think about a group of people combined with this chart line. Also, a magnet is not a bad idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used an extended "hand" silhouette holding a business card which has good recognition and is immediately associated with making business contacts.

The hand with the highest acceptance worked out to be hand on right reaching "back" toward the left. I favoured the hand on the left extending the card "forward" to the right (same as the reading direction). Your mileage might vary.

I further worked it into a brochure cover where the inside right pocket has a hand die-cut so that a real business card can be "taken" from the extended hand of the company president.

It's been wildly accepted.